# Aligning characters and integers in a user created table

Tags: c

i just finished a piece of code that gets names of foods and their weight and calories from a user, i.e. Apple 4oz 100 calories. I iterate through a loop and get several entries. My issue now is i cant seem to create a table with the characters lining up properly. Im supposed to align the names to their left edges, and all digits are aligned via their least significant digit (right aligned). Here is what i have so far but it does not seem to work for names that are small or larger than the rest and it shifts the integers either left or right.

```
while (PrintCnt < LUNCH_QTY)
    {
        printf("%-s %8d %10d\n", lunches[PrintCnt].name,
               lunches[PrintCnt].weight, lunches[PrintCnt].calories);
        PrintCnt++;
    }
```

This gives me:

[image]

How can I left align the names, and right align all the integers.

Thanks for all the help I'm new to C, and Im greener than a leprechaun riding a bullfrog through a St. Patties day parade!

Comment: ...followed by `%3d` instead of `%8d`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Im still getting miss matched data, for example if i put in like 1000 for the weight or calories it still miss aligns, is there not a simple way to right align integers

Comment: Well, space them accordingly. If you expect 4-figure values, use `%4d`. Otherwise you'll have to input all the data and use heuristics to figure out the widths. Note that you can use a variable for the width, eg. `printf("%*d", width, value);`

Comment: @WeatherVane...hand in face! LOL, yea a little change in numbers goes a long way...thanks anyways

Comment: see the edited comment too.